# Discrete distribution with adjustable variance

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, discrete-data

The variance of a binomial distribution is not adjustable. If you know its mean and the number of trials, the variance is also determined. I need a distribution that has an additional degree of freedom, where the variance and the mean are independent.

In other words, I need a discrete probability distribution with the following properties:

1. Its support is the integers $0, 1, 2, \dots, N$, where $N$ is a non-negative integer (the number of trials, in analogy to the binomial distribution).
2. The distribution is symmetric around $N/2$, which is also the mean.
3. The variance is a free parameter that I can adjust (within a feasible range, see comments).
4. For suitable parameters, the variance should go to zero if $N$ is even, or to $1/4$ if $N$ is odd (the variance of drawing one of $(N-1)/2$ or $(N+1)/2$ at random).

The binomial distribution with $p=1/2$ fulfills 1. and 2., but fails at 3 and 4, because the variance is a function of $p$ and $N$. Is there *any* other discrete probability distribution that meets these requirements?

Comment: The binomial distribution doesn't satisfy 2 unless p=1/2. The terminology "variance and mean are independent" makes no sense.  I think you mean that that given that the mean is specified (say N/2) the variance is a single parameter that is not a function of the mean of the distribution.

Comment: It must be the case that you are looking for a distribution that doesn't involve independent trials with a constant p because then the binomial is the only possibility.

Comment: @MichaelChernick In the binomial, the variance is determined from the mean in the sense that given the mean $=pN$, you can deduce $p$ and from there the variance. By "independent" I meant precisely what you said.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Of course, the discrete distribution I am looking for doesn't even have to be related to trials of any sort.

Comment: I agree with your last comment.  I am trying to think of distributions that satisfy 2 and 3 and what if anything conditions 1,2 and 3 do to restrict the variance.

Comment: I don't think there can be such a distribution without more constraints, as the support + the symmetry implies a strict maximum on the variance that is a function of the mean, namely, $N^2/4$ (with the distribution having $p(0) = p(N) = 1/2$, $p(\text{anything else}) = 0$.

Comment: @jbowman So the variance lies within an interval, $0 \le \sigma^2 \le N^2/4$. That's fine by me.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably just use a compound binomial distribution where $p$ follows some other symmetric distribution with mean = 0.5. The beta-binomial distribution comes to mind. You just have to make sure your $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are equal so $p$ has reflection symmetry about the mean. You can increase and decrease them **together** to adjust the variance and leave the mean unchanged, as you wish according to the compound variance formula.

Comment: Oh, almost. I realize I need the variance to go to zero for a suitable choice of parameters. I have added this requirement to the question. The beta-binomial does not satisfy it.

Comment: I am sorry for changing the question.